# How can I determine the origin of the cross-origin frame throwing a CORS Exception?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, iframe, cross-domain

I am running into a bug in a complex frameset in a complex code base, where I receive the javascript error:

This is being triggered when trying to access the `document` value of the cross origin frame.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://originA.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Is there any way that I troubleshoot this error and determine what the second origin is (not originA)? This error is vague and trying to access the .location property of the frame also gives the same error.

I also tried to launch Chrome with `--disable-web-security` to try to troubleshoot, but the same error was thrown.

All I would like is a clue of what exactly this cross-origin frame that is trying to be accessed is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround this in Firefox. When I used Firefox and downloaded a "Cors Everywhere" extension, this did still not enable the functionality, but the console error details reported the frame's URL, helping me identify the problem.